# Explanation of 'or' in exception syntax, why is it valid syntax and how does it work?

Tags: python, exception

A colleague of mine mistakenly typed this (simplified) code, and was wondering why his exception wasn't getting caught:

```
>>> try:
...     raise ValueError
... except IndexError or ValueError:
...     print 'Caught!'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError
```

Now I know that the correct syntax to catch both types of exception should be `except (IndexError, ValueError):`, but why is the above considered valid syntax? And how does it work?

For example, the above code will throw a `ValueError` and it won't get caught. But take this code:

```
>>> try:
...     raise IndexError
... except IndexError or ValueError:
...     print 'Caught!'
... 
Caught!
```

The `IndexError` will get caught. How is the `or` evaluated, and what is it evaluated to?!

Thanks for any light you can shed!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because `IndexError or ValueError` is evaluated to `IndexError`.

```
>>> IndexError or ValueError
<type 'exceptions.IndexError'>
```

The `or` operator returns the first expression that evaluates to `True` (In this case `IndexError`), or the last expression, if none of them are `True`.
So, your except statement is actually equivalent to:

```
except IndexError:
```

Comment: Duh!!! I knew that.... I just didn't apply it here. I also knew that the `except` keyword takes statements... so I really should have figured that out. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The result of the Boolean operations `or` and `and` is always one of the operands, so `foo or bar` will evaluate to `foo` if `foo` is [truthy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), or `bar` if `foo` if falsy.

In this case both `IndexError` and `ValueError` are truthy so `IndexError or ValueError` evaluates to `IndexError`, and your except statement is equivalent to `except IndexError`.